# What happens to a single Azure VM when a zone goes down

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

We have a service with low SLA requirements, so we host it on a single VM, no need for multiple VMs in availability set/zones.
What happens if there is a zone or fault domain failure?
Will Azure automatically reallocate the VM to an operational zone / host (FD), or we have to actively restart or redeploy the VM in order to reallocate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/manage-availability#understand-vm-reboots---maintenance-vs-downtime), when facing an unexpected Downtime, Azure will migrate your VM to a healthy physical machine in the same datacenter.

> When detected, the Azure platform automatically **migrates (heals) your
> virtual machine to a healthy physical machine in the same datacenter**.
> During the healing procedure, virtual machines experience downtime
> (reboot) and in some cases loss of the temporary drive. The attached
> OS and data disks are always preserved.

However, if you are using a single VM, it's recommended to use **Standard SSD** wither higher SLA.

> A single instance virtual machine with a Standard SSD will have an SLA
> of at least 99.5%, while a single instance virtual machine with a
> Standard HDD will have an SLA of at least 95%. See [SLA for Virtual
> Machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_9/).

Comment: Thanks, per this document I now understand that Azure will move the VM to a healthy host on the same DC.
I wonder what happens in case of a DC / Zone failure, again for a single VM deployment. will the VM be moved to a new zone or just left on faulty zone?

Comment: Per my understanding. For a single VM without availability set/zones. By default, it has no infrastructure redundancy required(you can check this when you deploy VM via Azure portal). In case of n case of a DC / Zone failure, Azure guarantees for Single Instance Virtual Machines based on Storage type.  That is [What Azure Availability Zones Are and Why You Should Use Them](https://dzone.com/articles/what-are-azure-availability-zones-and-why-should-y)